# help in performing date arithmetic with timestamp values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I need some help in constructing an oracle query that will pull values for 2 days previous.

The `timestamp` column (number) values look like this `201106210000`.
The other date like number columns have values like this:
 `year=2011 quarter=2 month=6 day=20`

Where does it make sense to do the date arithmetic? using the timestamp or should I used these other calendar columns?

The table also has these date attributes:

```
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 YEAR                           NUMBER
 QUARTER                        NUMBER
 MONTH                          NUMBER
 DAY                            NUMBER
 HOUR                           NUMBER
 TIMESTAMP                      NUMBER
 CNT_N                                          NUMBER
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this table is a crappy way to store dates (which hopefully you are aware of).  Why not either a DATE or TIMESTAMP column?

If that is out of your control, I would recommend using a to_date() on a concatenation of the YEAR, MONTH, and DAY columns so you have an actual DATE to work with.  Something like:

```
select *
from table
where to_date(year||'/'||month||'/'||day, 'YYYY/MM/DD') >= trunc(sysdate) - 2
```

Since your columns aren't real date columns you would need a function-based index to avoid a full table scan using this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from TABLE1 

where
to_date( to_char(DAY,'00')   || 
         to_char(MONTH,'00') || 
         to_char(YEAR,'0000'), 'ddmmyyyy') < sysdate-2   
/* substitute sysdate-2 with any date but becareful of using EQUAL 
because sysdate will have a timestamp, so use Greater Than or LessThan */
```

However, if you require time as well, here is the code

```
select * from TABLE1 

where
to_date( 
to_char(DAY,'00') || 
to_char(MONTH,'00') ||
to_char(YEAR,'0000') || ' ' || 
to_char(HOUR,'00'), 'ddmmyyyy hh24') 
< sysdate-2   

/* I don't know if you have a field for minutes and seconds ,
 but I am sure you get the idea*/
```